# Why does the template function that takes c-strings as arguments return ab as the greater value while the others return ac?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

The template function takes two values as arguments and returns the greatest value. I've also noticed that (at least for visual studios) the code won't compile depending on if you mismatch the arguments passed to the functions so that getMax() won't compile if you pass it the c-string variables, and getMax<char*>() won't compile if passed a string literal (or a string).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class myType>
myType getMax(myType x, myType y)
{
    return (x > y ? x : y);
}

int main() {
    string str1 = "ab";
    string str2 = "ac";

    char str3[] = "ab"; 
    char str4[] = "ac";

    cout << "1: No data type -- " << getMax("ab", "ac") << endl;
    cout << "2: char*        -- " << getMax<char*>(str3, str4) << endl;
    cout << "3: string       -- " << getMax<string>("ab", "ac") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the questioned cases, all that is being compared are pointer address values; what they point to is never considered. The `std::string` expansion uses the [`operator >` overload for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), which *does* consider content.

Comment: Forget that it's a template; that's a distraction. Just write an ordinary function and play around with it.